# Can I delete a GitHub fork before it's merged, or do I have to wait until after?

Tags: github

I forked a GitHub repo and submitted a Pull Request. But now my account still has a copy of the original repository.

Must I have that repo on my account enabled/present until the merge is done or I can delete it?

Since I don't plan to add more features it would be a waste of space.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must keep the forked repo around until the merge is done; otherwise, GitHub will not keep your changes.

Additionally, it isn't really a waste of space since GitHub allows unlimited open repos for no cost, and lesser used repos drop off the list of recently contributed repos on the front page, so you won't ever see it.

If you are talking about your local checkout of the fork, there is absolutely no need to keep that. All your changes are now stored on GitHub, so what you do with the local copy doesn't matter - just don't delete the repo on GitHub before the PR is merged.